# AngularJS - Sequentially Setting a Scope to True

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Within my HTML page, i have a number of $scope's (nearly 25) titled `OpenAll`. They are displayed in `div`'s, `section`'s, `table`'s etc.

e.g 1:

```
<div class="content" ng-class="{active: OpenAll}">
    //Some HTML code
</div>
```

e.g 2:

```
<table class="blocks" ng-show="OpenAll">
    //Some HTML code
</table>
```

e.g 3:

```
<section class="outline" ng-if="OpenAll">
    //Some HTML code
</section>
```

Within my JS file, this value is set to `true` during one of the steps in execution of a function:

```
$scope.OpenAll= true;
```

How can i adapt my JS file to loop through all the `OpenAll` scopes in my HTML file, and set them to `true` one by one?

So, look for the first `OpenAll` scope, set that to `true`, search for the 2nd `OpenAll` and set to true, then 3rd, 4th, 5th etc....

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use one `OpenAll` property in your `$rootScope`? You can access it everywhere with `$rootScope.OpneAll`.

Comment: @FlorianGl - I need to set the first OpenAll scope in the HTML page to true, after that, the second, then third etc... Does $rootScope allow this?

Comment: Rootscope will set all openAll to true irrespective of the order.

Comment: Didn't get that the order was relevant, so forget my comment^^

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by OpenAll scope (because OpenAll is a property), and also by first, second OpenAll scope, etc. These are independent scopes, or nested scopes ?

Comment: As @Tiborg already asked, what do you mean by "OpenAll scope"? Do you have 25 different $scopes, all with a property named "OpenAll"?